# Run R shiny plotting function with JS in an R Shiny environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, plotly

I have a shiny app which adds a gridstack.js gridstack panel to the app whenever I click a button. Now, I would like to add a plot to the panel.
Here is my code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyjqui)
library(gridstackeR)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage (
  useShinyjs(),
  includeCSS("www/app.css"),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/10.0.1/gridstack-all.min.js", type='module'),
    tags$script(HTML('
      function addFirstWidget() {
        var grid = document.querySelector(\'.grid-stack\').gridstack;
        grid.addWidget({h:5, w: 2, content: \'This is where the plot goes\'});
      }
    '))
          
  ),
  grid_stack(id="mygrid"),
  actionButton("first_widget", "First Widget"),
  
  title = "Gridstack Prototype"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$first_widget, {
    # browser()
    runjs("addFirstWidget();")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The JS Function addFirstWidget() makes a new gridstack panel whenever the button is pressed.

I want to call a function that renders a plot in plotly, ggplot, or some other plotting library within the panel(I'll know what library I use for the plot), for instance, this:

```
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about actually putting this interactive plot into the panels. The interactivity must be kept, and I can't use JS to generate the plots

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include the JavaScript library since it is included by the R package.

Here is a way using `insertUI`. But you have to give `w` and `h` in the UI. I firstly tried to insert `grid_stack_item(plotlyOutput(......` and that was not nice.

```r
library(shiny)
library(gridstackeR)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  grid_stack(
    id = "mygrid",
    grid_stack_item(
      id = "widget1",
      w = 6, h = 6 
    )
  ),
  
  actionButton("first_widget", "First Widget"),
  
  title = "Gridstack Prototype"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$pltly <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$first_widget, {
    insertUI(
      "#widget1",
      where = "afterBegin",
      plotlyOutput("pltly")
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```